# keyboard input on bash scripts executed within 2nd bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to download a file and run it using the following script:

```
wget https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd npm-g_nosudo-master
./npm-g-no-sudo.sh
cd ../
rm -rf npm-g_nosudo-master
rm master.zip
```

The downloaded script pauses twice requiring user input:

1. an 'enter' key press
2. an 'y' followed by an 'enter'

How can I include this input in the above script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the downloaded script is just reading from stdin, you can simply `echo` or `printf` the inputs:

```
echo -e "\ny\n" | ./npm-g-no-sudo.sh
```

Or:

```
printf "\ny\n" | ./npm-g-no-sudo.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

In the bash script: https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo/blob/master/npm-g-no-sudo.sh  ,you can find

```
read -p "Do you wish to update your .bashrc/.zshrc file(s) with the paths and manpaths? [yn] " yn
```

on line 142, which means that you need to type something when you run this bash script.

So, one way to solve your problem is to fork this repo and modify it.